# Ignite server: "All server nodes for the following caches have left the cluster"

Tags: ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.7.6. I'm trying to run 2 servers with full caches replication and persistent storage.
Both servers have the same settings, all the caches are created in REPLICATED mode.

But when I stop the first run server, the second one outputs the following:

```
All server nodes for the following caches have left the cluster: caches' names
```

And from that moment the enumerated caches become unavailable to the clients until I start the first server instance.

Comment: Do you have persistence configured? Are you sure that server nodes actually formed a cluster (check `Topology snapshot` messages?)

Comment: Yes, persistence is configured and a cluster is formed - I can restore data from the persistence and I see topology changes, in particular, these two servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your baseline topology? I am afraid that only one server node is in BLT. You should add both nodes:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/baseline-topology#section--getting-node-consistent-id-

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't call setBaselineTopology at all. Thanks!